# Tables inside table repeat both <thead> when print as PDF

Tags: html, pdf, html-table

I have a thead tag inside a table, and the headers in thead will repeat on each page when printing the page as PDF. There are 2 sections in the table and each has its own header, and the entire big table has its own header.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th></tr>@*main header should always repeat in each page on the print out.*@
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>@*I need  Headers for 1st section to repeat in print out when the lines in section 1 cross 2 pages, and the main header should always repeat in each page.*@
            <td>Header 1 for 1st section</td> 
            <td>Header 2 for 1st section</td>
            <td>Header 3 for 1st section</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>1st section line 1</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>1st section line 2</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>1st section line 3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>@*I need  Headers for 2nd section to repeat in print out when the lines in section 2 cross 2 pages, and the main header should always repeat in each page.*@
            <td>Header A for 2nd section</td> 
            <td>Header B for 2nd section</td>
            <td>Header C for 2nd section</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>2nd section line 1</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2nd section line 2</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2nd section line 3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the headers for 1st section to repeat in print out when the lines in section 1 cross 2 pages, the headers for 2nd section to repeat in print out when the lines in section 2 cross 2 pages, and the main header should always repeat in each page.

I tried many different ways to do it, but none of them works.

Any idea, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like putting the main header in a table/thead and then in that body put one row, one cell. Inside that cell put the two other tables with their headers and content. Thus breaking in the table would repeat both the outside table (main header) and the inside table headers. This is how it would be done in most publishing systems using XSL FO, just not sure it works in HTML.

Comment: Yes, I did. Only the inside thead repeated. The thead in the main table didn't repeat.

Comment: Too bad. Trying to create complex print documents using browser print functionality will likely fall short in many cases, like this one. Browsers have yet to understand the complexities of print publishing.

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tried? They do repeated-header stuff differently.

Comment: Internet explorer 11. The users maninly use internet explorer.

Comment: @KevinBrown Setting up a report server for SSRS in not an option for the time being. Do you have any other suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Try wrapping the `<tr />` inside `<tbody />` with `<thead />`

```
<tbody>
 <thead> 
   <tr><th>My Sub titles</th></tr>
 <thead>
</tbody>
```

Option 2: Have a different schema for rendering such hierarchy of tables

```
<table>
 <thead>Main Headers</thead>
 <tbody>
    <table>
     <thead>Sub Headers</thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Option 2 works, thanks. Option 1 didn't work for me.